# PHP: Array to string conversion

Tags: php

We're running `PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.15 with Suhosin-Patch`, and I just ran across the weirdest thing. I keep getting an Array to string conversion error.

Here is some code with line numbers:

```
115 $report['report'][$key]['report'] = array();
116 watchdog('ranking_report_field', 'key is a: ' . gettype($key), array(), WATCHDOG_NOTICE);
117 $report['report'][$key]['report'] = array(
    '#markup' => "<p>No information available.</p><p>For questions, <a href='mailto:$emailAddr'>email</a> your account executive ($emailAddr).</p>",
);
```

Here are Drupal's (sequential) logs for those line numbers:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in foo() (line 115 of /var/www/...
key is a: string
Notice: Array to string conversion in foo() (line 117 of /var/www/...
```

So far as I can tell there's no array to string conversion that should be taking place. Someone help me out with a second pair of eyes, please - or is this some kind of bug that just hit PHP?

Comment: http://sscce.org ...

Comment: try `var_dump($report);`

Comment: What is the value of `$key`? Then does `$report['report'][$key]` already exist and is an array?

Comment: Sorry guys, I'll update the question to be a little more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the array keys is mapped to a string not an array. Here is a program for how such an error could occur.

```
<?php

$key = 0;

$report = array();
$report['report'] = array();
$report['report'][$key] = 'report';

// Array to string conversion error
$report['report'][$key]['report'] = array();

// what I assume you are expecting is
$report['report'][$key] = array();
$report['report'][$key]['report'] = array(); // no more notices
```

*NOTE: at his time the OP has not included info for how the array is created*

Comment: I don't understand. What is all this? What is "the seconds report key"?

Comment: It looks like I was loosing my mind. The structure of `$report` was intermittently changing, so I was having trouble tracking this one down. Thanks for your help robbmj!